# Bootstrap Flex and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Holla! So, I am planning to make my UI look even more better by aligning the contents i.e. `style={{textAlign:"justify"}}`.

So the items will occupy the full width of the `Row` by expanding itself if need be.

> The UI looks like this for now.
> [image]

Here is my object (ignore the same `Id`)

```
const smartphones = [
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Apple"},
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Samsung" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Google" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Xiomi" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Huawei" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Xiomi" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "LG" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Nokia" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Huawei" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Xiomi" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "LG" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Nokia" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Apple"},
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Samsung" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Google" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Xiomi" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Huawei" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "Xiomi" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101,  description: "LG" },
    { topSearchCardId: 101, description: "Nokia" },
```

And here is my `flex` buddy. I am using `React` so therefore its `className`.

```
<Row>
  <div className="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 widget-tag">
    {smartphones.map((report, key) => (
      <Link to="#">
        <div className="badge font-size-14 p-4 py-2 bg-light text-dark">{report.description}</div>
      </Link>
    ))}
  </div>
</Row>
```

Updated Image. using `justify-content:space-between;` (This is what I wanted.)

[image]

Uisng `.widget-tag{`

[image]

Comment: Hello Mate, Where are you from? 
It seems you are creating a React App and using Reactstrap or ReactBootstrap. Right?

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yes I am using React-Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **flexbox** I believe, `justify-content:space-between;` would probably do this. However it would set uneven gaps in between as your flex-items are not of equal widths.

And other option would be you can use **CSS-Grid** and all your children buttons would be of equal width:

So, on your parent element (which will become your parent container), you can use the following:

```
.widget-tag{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);
}
```

And you can play around as per your requirement.

Comment: Great Bro. I just updated my question with the outputs for both, Preferably I would be using ```justify-content:space-between```. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sahil You are most welcome. God Bless you. And Eid Mubarak